# Android : sqlite record insert works once but not twice

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am trying to add "player names" to a table in my database.  It is inserting the first one perfectly fine and then crashes on the second name.

public void addTeam1Members() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    EditText playername, playerinit;
    DBAccessMatch dbAccess = new DBAccessMatch(this);

    String pname, pinit;
    dbAccess.open();
    for (int x = 0; x < team1Players; x++) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0:

            playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTeam1Player1);
            GlobalVars.setTeam1PlayerNames(playername.getText().toString(),
                    x);
            GlobalVars.sT1P1 = playername.getText().toString();
            playerinit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTeam1Player1Init);
            GlobalVars.setTeam1PlayerInit(playerinit.getText().toString(),
                    x);
            if (playername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() == true) {
                pname = " ";
            } else {
                pname = playername.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            if (playerinit.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() == true) {
                pinit = " ";
            } else {
                pinit = playerinit.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pname + " - " + pinit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dbAccess.createPlayer(pname, pinit);
            break;
        case 1:
            playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTeam1Player2);
            GlobalVars.setTeam1PlayerNames(playername.getText().toString(),
                    x);
            GlobalVars.sT1P2 = playername.getText().toString();
            playerinit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTeam1Player2Init);
            GlobalVars.setTeam1PlayerInit(playerinit.getText().toString(),
                    x);
            if (playername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() == true) {
                pname = " ";
            } else {
                pname = playername.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            if (playerinit.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() == true) {
                pinit = " ";
            } else {
                pinit = playerinit.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pname + " - " + pinit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dbAccess.createPlayer(pname, pinit);
            break;
```

This is a small chunk of the code which shows player 1 and player 2.  They are ultimately identical other than the edittext boxes they inhabit.

when createPlayer(name,initial) runs the first time it inserts perfectly, then the second time it does not.

```
    public void createPlayer(String playername, String playerinitials) {

    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_PLAYERNAME, playername);
        cv.put(KEY_PLAYERINITIALS, playerinitials);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, cv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(null);
        d.setTitle("Dang it!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(null);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: No Error is coming up, it simply crashes out of the program.  LogCat is not saying anything either however it will not add a second person.

Comment: If the program is "crashing" there has to be some sort of error. If not - helping you will be very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research on the issue I could not determine what the error was (using logcat).  I moved the "create user" function elsewhere and did it outside of this class and everything worked fine.